# update issue in laravel with validation

Tags: laravel

how to validate if i am upadting the whole profile with email the email validation is working gud. But when i update the profile without changing email the validation not let the code run. Please let me know how to fix it that email should b unique but when i don't change the email it also update the profile

```
        $validation_rules['user_id'] = 'required';
        $validation_rules['name'] = 'required';
        $validation_rules['email'] = 'email|required|unique:users,email';
        $validation_rules['phone'] = 'required';
```

Comment: You can define different rules depending on update or create. If you email is not required on update then you do not need to set the rule to required.

Comment: But the problem is email id should be unique. And when i update profile and don't make any changes in email the code does'nt run

Comment: why dont you just provide the mail on updating? even if it didn't chane? otherwise make in unique but not required for updates https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update

Answer (score 0):

```
$validation_rules['user_id'] = 'required';
$validation_rules['name'] = 'required';
$validation_rules['phone'] = 'required';

if (Request::isMethod('put')) {
    //which is update
    $validation_rules['email'] = 'email|required';
}else{
    // if it is not 'put', it is 'post' which is an insert
    $validation_rules['email'] = 'email|required|unique:users,email';
}
```

Let me know if that worked